# How to send datadog event stream data into datadog logs?

Tags: devops, monitoring, datadog

Actually, we have two datadog accounts: Let me consider it has account A and account B.
when I push the message to data dog event using API I am able to see the events in events stream and I am able to see the same thing in logs also in the account A.
But when I do the same thing in account B I am able to see the data in event stream but not in logs.
can I know what might be the reason ???
Am I missing something to enable ??
if so can someone help me with this?

BELOW CODE IS USED TO PUSH THE EVENT TO DATA EVENTS STREAM.

```
from datadog import initialize, API

options = {
    'api_key': '<DATADOG_API_KEY>',
    'app_key': '<DATADOG_APPLICATION_KEY>'
}

initialize(**options)

title = "Something big happened!"
text = 'And let me tell you all about it here!'
tags = ['version:1', 'application:web']

api.Event.create(title=title, text=text, tags=tags)

# If you are programmatically adding a comment to this new event
# you might want to insert a pause of .5 - 1 second to allow the
# event to be available.
```

Answer (score 0):

That endpoint is used to send events to Datadog, if your one account is sending them to the logs product, it is most likely because that account has a special flag that converts all your incoming events into logs. This is common for users that use the Security Monitoring product.

I would recommend reaching out to support@datadoghq.com to see if this flag is enabled in that one account. And if you want to replicate that behavior in another account, you can ask them to enable that feature.